# Expand the group in expandable listview while searching from searchview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-fragments, expandablelistview

I have one expandable listview in fragment which contains the section and under which I have different products. I have searchview in action bar, from where I am searching the products.

Now what I have done is while loading the listview , I collapse all the groups,now when user start searching for products, I want to filter the respective group, which i have done,but the result is the group is not getting expanded,(hope I am not making thing very confusing...)

[image]

Now here I am searching product name "sony" in searchview and I am getting the filter result but the group is not expanding, I want to expand the group and show the product name which comes under the relevant group.

**I have created this two methods :**

```
private void expandAll()
    {
        int count = listAdapter.getGroupCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            expListView.expandGroup(i);
        }
    }

    private void collapseAll()
    {
        int count = listAdapter.getGroupCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            expListView.collapseGroup(i);
        }
    }
```

I have called the collapseAll() method when my fragment load the data in the expandable listview.

So now if I called the expandAll() method while searching the product and not getting the expected result.

**This is how I filter the list :**

```
public void filterData(String query)
        {
            //query = query.toLowerCase();
            //query=query;

            ArrayList<ProSectionName> filterProSectionNames=prepareFilterListData(query);

            if(query.isEmpty())
            {
                if(txtNoProductMessage.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
                {
                    txtNoProductMessage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                listDataHeader.addAll(mNewTopupGroupCollection);
            }

            if(filterProSectionNames!=null && filterProSectionNames.size()>0)
            {
                if(txtNoProductMessage.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
                {
                    txtNoProductMessage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                listDataHeader.clear();

                for(ProSectionName proSectionName : mNewSectionGroupCollection)
            {
                ArrayList<ProSectionName.Products> productList = proSectionName.getProductList();
                ArrayList<ProSectionName.Products> newProductList = new ArrayList<ProSectionName.Products>();

                for(ProSectionName.Products products : productList)
                {
                    if(products.getProductName().toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()) ||products.getProductName().toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()))
                    {
                        newProductList.add(products);
                    }
                }

                if(newProductList.size() > 0)
                {
                    ProSectionName proSectionName = new ProSectionName(ProSectionName.getsectionName(),newProductList);
                    listDataHeader.add(topupSectionName);
                    //expandAll();
                }
                else
                {
                    txtNoProductMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    txtNoProductMessage.setText("No Match Found...");
                }
            }
            //Log.v("MyListAdapter", String.valueOf(topupProducts.size()));
        }
        else
        {
            txtNoProductMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txtNoProductMessage.setText("No Match Found...");
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

The problem I am facing is when I called the `expandAll()` in my `filterdata()` my listgroup get expanded properly but my soft keyboard gone. I want to keep keyboard there also until user press back.

Comment: since you can make out which group contains the items you are searching for, why dont you expand the group using the position ??

Comment: @TheUnknown can you please explain a bit more about this? any snippet sample(psuedo) code will be helpful...

Comment: You already know which parent group to display correct (if that is what you meant by saying "i want to filter the respective group, which i have done,but the result is the group is not getting expanded"), in that case, u cud loop through may b and get the positions of each parent group and instead of calling collapse, call expand .

Comment: And if notifydata set changed does not work , try setting the adapter again, cz at times it really does not work.

Comment: I think, you should concentrate on how `SearchView` is losing its focus. Perhaps, you added some listeners to it and they make the keyboard hide. Could you add the code where you manipulate the `SearchView`?

Comment: You may play with `setDescendantFocusability` on the `ViewGroup` (layout) containing the listview.

Comment: Hello @AndroidLearner:
when you search the data in your dataset, that time you also get the groupNumber in seperate arraylist, like example you find the "Rose" word in your dataset. And it's contain 10 places that time you get all group number.
when your loading functionality done that time you call your expandAll() method around your groupnumber list..

Answer (score 4):

It will work as The Unknown told, as follws

1. From search, find out the group position/number of target, say target belongs to `n` group in your data adapter.
2. Call `expListView.smoothScrollToPosition(n);`
3. Call  `expListView.expandGroup(n);`

That's all no need to call any extra method. The SoftKey will remain on screen as it was.